# Jenkins downstream jobs not triggering from Build Flow job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed an build flow plugin for polling and multiple jobs are running. At the end of execution, based on SUCCESS/FAILURE i'm trying to trigger a "Downstream job" which is not triggering.

Anyone faced the similar issue? or please help what could be the reason?
[image]

In the above screen shot i have a set of Jobs running in sequence/parallel (in define build flow using DSL section). and below that in "Post build actions section, configured downstream job named "STOP & FIX disable" which is not triggering after success in my case.

Comment: Please add a code snippet with what you've tried. This is really hard to guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer for this after spending long time. In the Flow section check "Flow run needs a workspace" and copy the content from "Define build flow using flow DSL" box and save it in a file(any name without extension) and provide the full path to the file path. It works!!